# Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).concat is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a `react` project, I used `Material UI` and for pagination, I should pass `rowsPerPageOptions` as props with an array value, But I wanna this array doesn't have duplicated item, so I decide to create a `Set` and then convert it to an array, so I wrote below code:

```
<TablePagination
  ~~~
  rowsPerPageOptions={[...new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])]}
  ~~~
/>
```

And I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).concat is not a function
```

When I use `Array.from` everything works well, but why spread operator of `ES6` doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: @zfrisch, I used `Array.from` and wait for a good answer.